# Excel protect workbook with password but allow readonly

Tags: c#, excel, interop

Using the interop classes in C# I was able to protect a workbook for reading and writing with a password.

[image: Password Dialog]

But I want users to be able to open the sheet as read-only.

[image: Read Only Dialog]

Is this possible without using the [`Workbook.SaveAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas.aspx) method?

Protecting a workbook with a password (picture 1) I'm using the [`Workbook.Password`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.password.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.readonlyrecommended.aspx), the only way to change the `Workbook.ReadOnlyRecommended` property is with the `Workbook.SaveAs` method.

In needed precisely what you're looking for a while ago (i.e. setting it without saving), but had to give in and use `SaveAs`. To my knowledge it's the only way.

Comment: Mh, ok... Then I have to save the file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `Workbook.Open()`. The 3rd parameter is the read only property.

Plus a link to to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms260757%28v=office.11%29)

Comment: Already set this to true. I also want to protect the sheet for further changes from unauthorised users.