# ClosedXML save workbook to prompt for readonly open

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, openxml, closedxml

Using ClosedXML (v0.93.1) on .Net Core 2.0, attempting to save a workbook so that when opened it prompts the user to open as "Read Only" or enter the protected password. (See linked question below).

I have seen `IXLWorksheet.Protect()` and `XLWorkbook.Protect()` - these correctly protect the workbook but still default the user to open with R/W access. This is a problem because it write locks the file and my process can't overwrite it until the user closes excel.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138099/excel-protect-workbook-with-password-but-allow-readonly/13146602#13146602) indicates OpenXML (the underlying API for ClosedXML) has the ability to set this when saving a workbook, however ClosedXML `XLWorkbook.SaveAs(SaveOptions)` doesn't include this. Perhaps I can't find the closedxml documentation on this option, but I believe this is the option I need.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52431042/3685882) and the attached github/MSDN links OpenXML doesn't support password protecting but I don't see any info about readonly open other than the first linked question saying it should be possible.

Code example:

```
XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
var ws = wb.AddWorksheet("My Sheet");

// ... add to worksheet

ws.Protect("my-worksheet-password");
wb.SaveAs("C:\\my-workbook.xlsx", new SaveOptions { /* In OpenXML the option would exist during this save step. */ });
```

Comment: This will be fixed when this PR is merged and released. https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/pull/1054

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not supported by ClosedXML yet, but you can use OpenXml directly to set the require property. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.filesharing.readonlyrecommended?view=openxml-2.8.1

```
    private void GeneratePartContent(WorkbookPart part)
    {
        FileSharing fileSharing1 = new FileSharing(){ ReadOnlyRecommended = true };
        workbook1.Append(fileSharing1);
        part.Workbook = workbook1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the type of `workbook1` in your example? I'm attempting to save my `XLWorkbook` to memory stream and then open as `SpreadsheetDocument` to follow your suggestion.

Comment: Was able to achieve this using `SpreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.FileSharing = new FileSharing { ... };`